# Laravel routing to angular app folder

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-routing

I have the following laravel structure on view

```
-public
--site
---app (this one shoul hold an angular app)
---views (normal php views are stored here)
--routes.php
```

than I would like to create a route to my angular app which should communicate with the laravel restAPI

one of my route which is working

```
Route::get('blog', array('as' => 'article.list', function()
{
    return View::make('site::articles')->with('entries', Article::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get());
}));
```

but How would I route my angular app to app subfolder

```
Route::get('configurator', array('as' => configurator', function()
{
    // this won't work View [app.index] not found. 
    //return View::make('site::app.index');
}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a laravel view and then inside this view call your angular routes.

Comment: yepp that's how I made, but the question is if is a reliable way to do or not?

Comment: Yes it is. Check these tutorials for more details:
http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating

http://scotch.io/tutorials/php/create-a-laravel-and-angular-single-page-comment-application